How to prevent user delete for certain condition?
We have a custom subscription system which is linked to user. Some time, many spam accounts are registered and we delete them. We do not want to delete a subscriber account, since that causes issues with subscription records and the recurring payments.
How can we restrict deleting an account when some conditions are met?

@mona-lisa solution works but triggers an error on hook_entity_predelete(), gives a weird message, and does not show my custom message.
This is my solution.
function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_cancel_form') {
    $uid = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRawParameter('user');
    $user = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('user')->load($uid);
    if ($uid) {
      $status = \Drupal::service('subscription.data_manager')->userHasSubscription($uid);
      if ($status) {
        \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('User %name - %mail has subscription with BBSRadio. You can not delete.',[
          '%name' => $user->getAccountName(),
          '%mail' => $user->getEmail(),
        ]));
        $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.user.collection');
        $redirect = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
        $redirect->send();
      }
    }
  }
  elseif ($form_id == 'user_multiple_cancel_confirm') {
    $has_subscription = 0;
    $last_user = null;
    $accounts = \Drupal::service('tempstore.private')
      ->get('user_user_operations_cancel')
      ->get(\Drupal::currentUser()->id());
    foreach ($accounts as $account) {
      $status = \Drupal::service('subscription.data_manager')->userHasSubscription($account->id());
      if ($status) {
        $has_subscription = 1;
        $last_user = $account;
        break;
      }
    }

    if ($has_subscription) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t('User %name - %mail has subscription with BBSRadio. You can not delete.', [
        '%name' => $last_user->getAccountName(),
        '%mail' => $last_user->getEmail(),
      ]));
      $url = Url::fromRoute('entity.user.collection');
      $redirect = new RedirectResponse($url->toString());
      $redirect->send();
    }
  }
}


This solution will not prevent deleting users with Drush.

Except in the case that code is used in a module whose machine name is hook, that cannot be the code you are actually using. Then, it is true what @4uk4 said: You cannot redirect users from a hook_form_alter() implementation.

Sending a redirect response is not an option, custom code is not allowed.
To prevent user delete you could deny access to the submit button and display the message on the form:
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for user_cancel_form.
 */
function mymodule_form_user_cancel_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $user = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  if ($certain_condition) {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#access'] = FALSE;
    \Drupal::messenger()->addError(t("You can't delete the user %name!", ['%name' => $user->getAccountName()]));
  }
}


Implement hook_entity_predelete in a custom module.
Get the entity type with $entity->getEntityTypeId().
Throw an exception if the user should not be deleted.
